# Where to put reusable HTML code in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm writing a rails app that allows users to delete records of various sorts. After pressing a delete button, I'd like to show a confirm dialog using [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals). I'd like to use this same dialog in several of my views, so I'll need to include the same HTML snippet in most of my pages.

I'm new to rails and I'm still learning the conventions.  Can anyone suggest the best (or standard) place to put the dialog code? Should it be a partial in `views/layouts/_confirm_delete_dialog.html.erb`, should it go inside `application.html.erb`, or should I put it somewhere else?

Thanks in advance for your advice,

D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your Views folder, you can create a general folder (called whatever you want). If you have a variable that you need to pass through to the general layout, you can definitely do so, but you will want to make sure that the information that you're passing through doesn't cause conflicts with the fields pulled from the model. For example, if you have two models and one has a public field but the other doesn't then you will not want to have a generic message that is using the public field. However, something like the created_at or updated_at would be okay.

You would use a code similar to,

`<%= render 'general/simple_message', :f => f %>`

In your views folder, you would have a directory called `general` and a file called `_simple_message.html.erb`.

Comment: Thanks kobaltz. Quick clarification though: should my file be named `_simple_message.html.erb` or just `simple_message.html.erb`, without the underscore? I initially tried it exactly as you suggested, but until I added the leading underscore I got a `Missing partial` error message. Should your answer be edited, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: As far as I know, for rails 3.X you do need the _ before your file's name